# Slow (considerable input lag, general slowness)

Tags: hardware

I am saddened to say that ElementaryOS is disappointingly slow on a Toshiba A85-S1072 laptop. Even typing has terrible lag,is there anything I can do to speed it up? Every other PC I have installed it on is wicked fast with it installed. Windows XP is faster than this!!! Any tips guys? Not a noob as far as windows goes (Sys Admin Level), but I want to learn more linux and this is a great starter OS.

Comment: You're talking about a laptop more that 10 years old. Any sysadmin should know that not all modern OS can run on it, and they should read  the requirements before install it. For more info: https://www.elementary.io/en/docs/installation#download-elementary-os

Comment: I have a 2007 Pentium Dual Core laptop with the same problem and have to use Windows 10 (telemetry OS)because of this problem.On a newer laptop (AMD A8-4500M) there isn't any typing lag.I don't think this is because of the old CPU but instead a bug in elementary OS since those old MS-DOS computers can type at fast speeds